# discord.py: Alternating 'playing' status wont work, commands disabled

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to have my bot display different messages in their 'playing' section, under the bots name.

I tried using a while loop and time to sleep between the different messages. This worked, but when i tried to use commands, it didn't register because (i think) it was stuck in a while loop and couldn't begin watching the messages for commands. Below is what i had:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('------------------------------------------------')
    print('Logged in as:')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------------------------------------------------')
    print("SubwayBot", version,"is connected and running!")
    print('------------------------------------------------')
    while True:
        await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='with !sbcmds'))
        time.sleep(10)
        await.client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='with my sub'))
        time.sleep(10) #it would return here and start the while loop again
client.run(TOKEN)
```

What i would like it to do is change the playing status, but also the commands to work.

Thanks in advance for all who attempt to find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should use `asyncio.sleep()` instead of `time.sleep()` because `time.sleep()` could block your whole bot and it does nothing else than "sleeping".

Instead of using a while loop in an event coroutine you should set up a [Background Task](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py). Hopefully that helps.